# R.array is a class but not an object?

Tags: java, android

This is for Android, but I believe it's a general Java question, so I'm labelling it as such.

I'm trying to use reflection on R.array to get an array from the list. The arrays are named `stringArraySubCategoryX` where X is replaced with a number from 0 to 20. This is my code, but I ran into a problem:

```
Field subCatField = R.array.class.getField("stringArraySubCategory" + position);
subCatergorySpinner.setAdapter(ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(InfoActivity.this, subCatField.getInt(R.array), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item));
```

The problem part is the `subCatField.getInt(R.array)` bit, which is supposed to return the resource int value of the selected array. But `Field.getInt(arg)`'s argument is an Object. I checked R.array, and that says `public static final class array`, but it seems that it's not accepted.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
subCatField.getInt(null)
```

Is what you're looking for. Provided the `stringArraySubCategoryX` is `static`, of course.

However ... you state: *"I'm trying to use reflection on R.array to get an array from the list."*

How is that an `int`?

```
subCatField.get(null)
```

will return the static `Object` contained in the `Field`

Comment: Correct - if the array is `static` you don't need an instance of the class and pass `null` instead.

Comment: In answer to your own question: Android has an object called R that has static int variables that represent all your resources that aren't the code itself (localized strings, images, so on). The ints are named after the filename or xml name= of each resource. I have a string-array in my strings.xml, but the resource identifier in R is an int that Context.getResources(int) uses to get the resource itself. Eg. getResources(R.array.stringArraySubCategory7)

Comment: Ahhh. Gotcha. Thanks for explaining (I haven't done any android programming ... though I really should, just to be familiar with it)